# How to check whether elements appears in the list only once in python?

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have a list:

```
a = [1, 2, 6, 4, 3, 5, 7]
```

Please, explain to me how to check whether element appears only once in in the list?

Please, also explain if all elements from 1 to `len(a)` are in the list. For instance, in list 'a' element from 1 to 7 are in the list, but if the list is `b = [1, 4, 3, 5]`, then not all elements from 1 to 4 are not in the list.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by *then not all elements from 1 to 4 are not in the list*? Where does *1 to 4* come from?

Comment: For your first question, do you want to check if *every* element appears only once, or if a *specific* element occurs only once in the list?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
len( set( a ) ) == len( a )
```

for the first question, and

```
( len( set( a ) ) == len( a ) == max( a ) ) and min( a ) == 1
```

for the second.

Comment: The second answer requires that all elements in `a` are integers.

Comment: I'd like this a lot more if it was written in pep8 style. As it stands, the code looks horrible.

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian: Yes, but I simply assumed that from the question :) – @Blue Peppers: Sorry, but I use too many different languages to have a different coding style for each one; and that's simply how I like it the most.

Answer (score 9):

When I read your question, I took a different meaning from it than mark did. If you want to check if a particular element appears only once, then

```
def occurs_once(a, item):
    return a.count(item) == 1
```

will be true only if `item` occurs in the list exactly once.

See Pokes answer for the second question

Comment: Aren't you assuming that the list doesn't contain doubles? Also, shouldn't you only check whether every element in `range(1,n+1)` is in  `a`?

Comment: `range` is a generator in newer Pythons.

Comment: Oh I see, I think we understood the question differently. I thought all the numbers from `1 - n` should be contained in the list, regardless of order and position, and might be mixed with other numbers as well.

Comment: @Herman, they couldn't possibly be mixed with other numbers regardless of how you read the question. `a = [1, 2, ..., len(a)]` must contain one copy of each number between 1 and `len(a)` if there is another number in there, then it doesn't satisfy the requirements. My method was wrong to not check min and max though. for example `[0, 1, 2, 7]` sums to 7 and beats my test without the check.

Answer (score 5):

For your first question if your elements are hashable you can create a set containing the elements and check its length:

```
len(set(a)) == len(a)
```

Alternatively you can use this function which can give better performance than the above if the result is False (but worse performance when the result is True):

```
def are_all_elements_unique(l):
    seen = set()
    for x in l:
        if x in seen:
            return False
        seen.add(x)
    return True
```

Answer (score 4):

For the second question you might want to check

```
sorted(a) == range(1, len(a) + 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

i understood you want something like that:

```
[x for x in a if a.count(x) == 1]
```